# Tkinter in python3, menubar does not working

Tags: python, tkinter, menubar

Well, i want to add menubar, but something is going wrong.

It says: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

My code:

```
from tkinter import *


class ApplicationWindow(Tk):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.geometry('800x400')
        self.f_app = Frame(self).pack()
        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        self.b_log = Button(self, width=10, text="Войти", command=self.func).pack()


    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

    def func(self):
        print("hello")

def main():
    # root = tk
    app = ApplicationWindow() 
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing your `ApplicationWindow` class without passing any arguments in, like this `app = ApplicationWindow()`.  In your `init` method, you give `master` a `None` default, and when you try to use `master.config` it says

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Try passing an argument in when you initialize the instance of `ApplicationWindow`.  Whatever it is that you want `master` to be (just not a `None` object).

I have updated your code (below) and it runs.  The button works, and the exit function closes the window.  There was a lot to fix, but it runs without error.  Take it from here:

```
import tkinter


class ApplicationWindow(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('800x400')
        self.master.f_app = tkinter.Frame(self.master).pack()
        menubar = tkinter.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        self.b_log = tkinter.Button(self.master, width=10, text="Войти", command=self.func).pack()


    def onExit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def func(self):
        print("hello")

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = ApplicationWindow(root) 
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an argument named `master=None` defaults to None. So when you create an instance of ApplicationWindow() without parameter your `master` argument gets None, and here you are calling `config()` method but your master is none and it doesnt have a method named config.

```
class ApplicationWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ...
        self.master.config(menu=menubar) # Error accurred here

def main():
    # root = tk
    app = ApplicationWindow() # pass an argument
```